# mockk, how to use slot for MutableMap<String, String>

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockk, mockk-verify

using mockk 1.9.3

having a function to be verified

class EventLogger private constructor()

```
fun logUserEvent(eventName: String?, eventParamMap: MutableMap<String, String>?) {
   ......
    internaLogEventImpl(eventName, eventParamMap)
}
```

internal fun internaLogEventImpl(eventName: String?, customParams: MutableMap<String, String>?) {
......
}

```
companion object {
     @Volatile
     private var sEventLoggerSingleton: EventLogger? = null

     @JvmStatic
    val instance: EventLogger
        get() {
            if (sEventLoggerSingleton == null) {
                sEventLoggerSingleton = EventLogger()
            }
            return sEventLoggerSingleton!!
        }
}
```

got compiler error at every {eventLogger.internaLogEventImpl(any(), mapSlot)}
[image]

Type mismatch.
Required: MutableMap<String, String>?
Found: CapturingSlot<MutableMap<String, String>>
when trying this below :

class TestK {

```
lateinit var eventLogger: EventLogger
lateinit var application: Application

val mapSlot = slot<MutableMap<String, String>>()

@Before
fun setUp() {
    application = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Application>()
    eventLogger = mockk.spyk(EventLogger.instance)
    ReflectionHelpers.setStaticField(EventLogger::class.java, "sEventLoggerSingleton", eventLogger)
}

@After
fun cleanUp() {
    ReflectionHelpers.setStaticField(EventLogger::class.java, "sEventLoggerSingleton", null)
}

@Test
fun logNotificationStatusChange_with_enabled_WhenCalled_ShouldLog() {

    val testMap = hashMapOf("action" to "open")

    every {eventLogger.internaLogEventImpl(any(), mapSlot)} answers {
        println(mapSlot.captured)
        assert(mapSlot.captured["action"] == "open")
    }
    eventLogger.logUserEvent("test_event", testMap)
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `capture` (see [Mockk's Capturing section](https://mockk.io/#capturing)).

So for your case `capture(mapSlot)` should work.

```kotlin
eventLogger.internaLogEventImpl(any(), capture(mapSlot))
```

---

Before trying to mock on complex code, It would be better to learn on easier example.

Here is a working example to mock a private call on an `object` with mockk.

```kotlin
object MyLogger {
    fun logUserEvent(event: String?, map: MutableMap<String, String>?) {
        // turns the event string into an uppercase string.
        internaLogEventImpl(event?.toUpperCase(), map)
    }

    private fun internaLogEventImpl(event: String?, map: MutableMap<String, String>?): Unit =
        throw Exception("real implementation")
}
```

How to test and mock the internal function so we don't throw the exception.

```kotlin
@Test
fun `test logger internal`() {
    val expectedMap = mutableMapOf("a" to "b")
    val expectedEvent = "EVENT"

    val mock = spyk(MyLogger, recordPrivateCalls = true)
    justRun { mock["internaLogEventImpl"](expectedEvent, expectedMap) }
    // or justRun { mock["internaLogEventImpl"](any<String>(), any<MutableMap<String, String>>()) }

    mock.logUserEvent("event", expectedMap)

    verify { mock["internaLogEventImpl"](expectedEvent, expectedMap) }
}
```

Here `logUserEvent` calls the real implementation and `internaLogEventImpl` calls the mock implementation.

if `justRun { mock["internaLogEventImpl"](expectedEvent, expectedMap) }` is not called (or wrong because the argument doesn't match), the real implementation will be call. Here it will throw `Exception("real implementation")`.

Please try and modify values to check different behaviors.

Comment: thx!. it helps for the compiler error, but the seems the code in answers block is not called though.

Comment: I added a working case which is similar to your issue. If you don't understand what is `spyk`, `justRun`, etc, mockk's [website](https://mockk.io/) is clear and It will be good for you to try simple case.

Comment: thx for put in extra sample! the key is shouldnt use the answers block but the verify.